# Can't boot into Windows without GRUB

Tags: linux, windows, grub

I have Windows 11 installed on my main SSD as a MBR/MSDOS Partition, as well as Linux in a secondary external hard drive as a GPT Partition. However, when I remove my external hard drive, my PC boots into GRUB recovery, saying that it can't find the device. GRUB is installed on the EHDD. What I want to do is boot from the Windows Boot Manager, which is still installed on a partition on my SSD. I can't boot into Windows even when the EHDD is connected.

Comment: Do you wish to remove the boot to Linux entirely and boot always only into Windows?

Comment: I would prefer still having both partitions but I can afford to nuke the Linux partition if that's easier than restoring from my backups

Comment: GRUB should be installed on the internal disk and Windows should be added to it. For a better user interface, you could use [Rescatux & Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/) to fix such problems.